# Change Handlebars notations

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

I have two teams working on the same project , both are using template engines ( Client and Server Side Engines ) with the same notations "{{X}}" but with different contexts .
now what I want to do is to change the [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) notations from {{ }} into something else for example <% %>

I want to use this notation for example :

```
    <div><%X%></div>
```

instead of :

```
    <div>{{X}}</div>
```

some edits needs to be done on the Handlebars.js , but I can't find it.
how can I do that ?

knowing that I can do it with [Mustache](https://raw.github.com/janl/mustache.js/master/mustache.js) by changing the line

```
exports.tags = ["{{", "}}"];
```

to

```
exports.tags = ["<%", "%>"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars is defined with a formal grammar. You need to change https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/src/handlebars.l

Answer (score 1):

You should really think twice before proceeding with this approach. Modifying [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and adding customized features is going to introduce several management issues that could possibly present a much higher cost at a later stages of the project. Consider these points:

1. If you modify the current version, it will be either very hard or time-consuming to keep up with future updates of the tool.
2. Current documentation and tutorials about the tool becomes obsolete or hard to follow.
3. Any new developers added to the project will need to adjust to the changes and try to understand the new features of the tool.

Given these points, I would suggest to follow the standards and best-practices provided by each third party tool.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: thanks, I understand the risk. but my question is how to do it?
if you have any idea please help me with it
thanks